# graphlab create dropna does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, graphlab

I'm testing graphlabe create with following

```
sf=gl.SFrame(['t1','t2','','t3','','t4'])
sf.dropna()
```

accoding to [graphlab api](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.dropna.html#graphlab.SFrame.dropna)

the above should remove empty values(na), but actually it does not, and no errors given either. anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  `''` is either `None` nor `NaN`:

```
import math

print(None == '')
print(float('nan')=='')
print(math.isnan(float('nan')))
```

Output:

```
False
False
True
```

Doku:   [dropna()](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.dropna.html#graphlab.SFrame.dropna)

> Remove missing values from an SFrame. A missing value is either `None` or `NaN`.

Your value `''` is neither so it stays.